# Sonarqube 7.2.1 badges returns 401

Tags: sonarqube

I have setup a couple of projects in Sonarqube 7.2.1. When i try to get the badges they return 401.

I was under the impression that anonymous users could see the badges, but apparantly i need to be logged in in sonarqube in order to see the badgets?

Is there any way to enable this behavior, or use tokens for it?